# Algorithm in array works for i=1 only

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Hello fellow eingineers/programmers. I'm calculating the course of the moment from right to left of a cantilever arm. **problem:** the algorithm works for a=0, a=1 and then it doesn't work. Code below:

objekte[] is an array of objects of two classes- Einzelmoment (moment) and Punktlast (single force).

```
for (int a = 0; a < verlauf[0].length; a++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < objekte.length; k++) {
            if (a == 0) {
                verlauf[0][0] = objekte[k].getLage();
                verlauf[1][a] = objekte[k].getKraft();

                if (objekte[k].getClass() == Punktlast.class) {
                    verlauf[2][a] = -(objekte[k].getKraft() * (objekte[a]
                            .getLage() - objekte[k].getLage()));
                } else if (objekte[k].getClass() == Einzelmoment.class) {
                    verlauf[2][a] = -(objekte[k].getMoment());
                }
            }
            else {
                verlauf[0][a] = objekte[k].getLage();
                verlauf[1][a] = objekte[k].getKraft() + verlauf[1][a - 1];

                if (objekte[k].getClass() == Punktlast.class) {

                    for (int j = 1; j == k; j++) {

                        if (objekte[k - j].getClass() == Einzelmoment.class) {

                            verlauf[2][a] += -(objekte[k - j].getMoment());

                        } else if (objekte[k - j].getClass() == Punktlast.class) {
                            verlauf[2][a] += -(objekte[k - j].getKraft() * (objekte[k- j].getLage() - objekte[k].getLage()));
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                }

                else if (objekte[k].getClass() == Einzelmoment.class) {
                    for (int j = 1; j == k; j++) {

                        if (objekte[k - j].getClass() == Einzelmoment.class) {

                            verlauf[2][a] += -(objekte[k - j].getMoment() + objekte[k].getMoment());

                        } else if (objekte[k - j].getClass() == Punktlast.class) {
                            verlauf[2][a] += -(objekte[k - j].getKraft() * (objekte[k- j].getLage() - objekte[k].getLage()));
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
            a++;
        }

    }
```

Hope somehow this makes sense. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjhox.png), it works for a=1 but it doesn't continue to the rest of the objects. Where's the problem in the code that it stops by a=1? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what you try to do or what `verlauf` is. I know what _Verlauf_ means, but why does `verlauf[0]` hold a position and `verlauf[1]` a force? Since the input isn't clear, the posted results don't make sense, either. What is the expected result? As a good engineer, you could post a sketch to clarify. `:)`

Comment: You are calculating section forces and moments along your beam. Are the loads (concentrated force; monent) independent or are the superimposed? You also use a strange kind of polymorphism here: `if (objekte[k].getClass() == Einzelmoment.class) ...` should probably be written as abstract function, so that your different loads can implement the desired behaviour in their class. The way you are doing it here is more like plain C than Java.

Comment: @MOehm I thought it too much to post whatever verlauf and objekte are. Verlauf has 3 rows and as manycolumns as a singly-linked list `kragarm` (not shown) has (as many loads a beam can have, it's variable). In the first row I should display the position the force has, in the second the vertical force until that point, and on the third row the moment up until that point. The exxpected result is a double[][] with those numbers. The loads are independent. The main prob here is, `a` doesn't increase after `a`=1 :(

Comment: (Using a spell checker isn't magic, even if working miracles.) `if (<anything>.getClass() ==` _is_ a _code smell_. Try to reconcile `if (a == 0)` and its `else`. Stare at `for (… ; j == k ; …)`. Use a debugger.

Comment: @greybeard code smell, never heard before! I already took down the `if(blah.getClass() ==` changed it for something "more elegant". What's a debugger? -> 2nd year civil engineer here, I'm the Jon Snow of programming. What's wrong with the `for(...; j ==k; ...`? Is it stuck because of the `j == k` ?

Comment: (`2nd year civil engineer here, I'm the Jon Snow of programming` - I almost imputed former FORTRAN experience.) `k` gets incremented in the outer loop, only. Thus, `j == k` can only be true _once_ in the inner loop(s) - if that.

Comment: `k` should stay as it is, I want `j` to increase its value until it's `k` so I can have access to all the elements before `objekte[k]` through `objekte[k-j]` and add them all together, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I might, the compiler won't unless you tell it: `for (… ; j <= k ; …)`.

Comment: THIS WAS IT! THANK YOU SO FREAKING MUCH!

Comment: are you good in programming? what does this test mean ? (int j = 1; j == k; j++) ? and why do you increase j++ twice once inside the loop header and once all by itself at the end fo the loop? these are points of contension make sure you understand logic fisrt before you program

Comment: @gpasch increasing `j` in multiple places: good catch. Even weirder is increasing `a` on different looping levels.

Comment: @gpasch I'm **not** good in programming, as you can see. I know that in the `for` I already increase `j` but when it doesn't work I play around with variables until I get the value that I need. In the end I took it out. I still don't know why I need to write `a++` at the end, but when I take it out, I get wrong values. Just go with the flow~~